# 17.10 stuck at "unlock your login keyring" on startup

Tags: 17.10, gnome-keyring

Recently I installed Ubuntu 17.10 on SSD drive. After few reloads with everything working fine, I got a message `Enter password to unlock your login keyring` on startup and it wants neither to accept my password nor to close the window or to press ANY button on it. So after entering the password it just dies and doesn't answer. Hope it's not the case to reinstall the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by killing the process `gnome-keyring-daemon` via virtual console. Although the interface looked different when I logged in. Having few other strange problems with 17.10 I decided to return back to 16.04. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯